# Visual Studio keeps moving code around

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a .aspx page developed in VS2010. Every time I make changes to the way the code is laid out (because VS2010 has moved stuff around) ... when I click 'Save' Visual Studio changes it back! What is going on?

I can write:

```
<div class="notes">
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>

<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server Text="Click Me" />
```

and, when I click save, Visual Studio changes it to

```
<div class="notes">
    <p>Hello</p></div><asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server Text="Click Me" />
```

What on earth is going on. I like to format my code neatly - properly indented and spaced - and Visual Studio keeps undoing my changes when I save! Help!

Comment: Do you by chance have the Format Document on Save extension installed?  https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ea1c920-69c4-441f-9979-ccc2752dac56

Comment: Looks like there are several other extensions that do this as well, so look through all of the extensions you have installed...

Comment: No. This just happens from time to time. It seems to pick on one area of a page and decides to cram a load of code together. I've rebuilt the solution, closed VS, rebooted the dev box and now it is okay ... until the next time.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Jscript  -> Formatting

Uncheck "Format completed line on Enter" and "Format completed block on }"

Or:

Go to:

1. Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Tabs -> Indenting
   , Select the None radio button.
2. Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Tabs > Miscellaneous
   , Uncheck Format HTML on paste.